# Calculating Floating point and precision

Tags: javascript, html, floating-point, precision

I have an assignment that wants me to calculate compound interest. I did most of the homework but I should display "Amount of deposit" with 2 decimal numbers for cents. But I tried several things like `parseFloat()` or `toFixed` but I can't still take the result with 2 precision I can only take `00.00`.
I need solution like this:

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="Cersoy-CNIT133-Assignments-4-part2" content="Cersoy-CNIT133-Assignments-4part2">
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>

<link href="../Assignment_all.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">



<title>Cersoy-CNIT133-Assignments_4-Part2</title>
<style>
    #main{
        background-color: burlywood;
        margin:  auto;
        height: 30%;
        width: 50%;
        padding: 1em;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }
    #table{
        border: solid 1px black;
    }
    th{
        border: solid 1px black;
    }
    td{
        border: solid 1px black;
    }  
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>
    
    <header>
        Cersoy-CNIT133-Assignments 4-Part2
    </header>
    <div id="main">
       <table id="table1" >
        <tr>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Amount of deposit</th>
            <th>Intrest Rate</th>
            
        </tr>
        <table id="table2" >
        <tr>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Amount of deposit</th>
            <th>Intrest Rate</th>
        </tr>
        <table id="table3" >
        <tr>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Amount of deposit</th>
            <th>Intrest Rate</th>
        </tr>
</table>
<script>
        
        
        
    var rate1=5;rate2=6;rate3=7;
   
     function addRow(a,b,c,t) {
    var table=0;
    if(t==1){table = document.getElementById("table1");}
  
    if(t==2){
    table = document.getElementById("table2");
    }
    else if(t==3){
    table = document.getElementById("table3");
    }
    
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    cell1.innerHTML = a;
    cell2.innerHTML = b;
    cell3.innerHTML = c;
    
     }
    function calc(rate,tab){
       var P=1000,A=0,n=0;
        
       
       r=rate.toFixed(2)
       r=r/100;
      
       
       
       for(n=0;n<=10;n++){
       
        A=(P*(1+r)^n);
        
        var fn,o;

        o = {style: "currency", currency: "USD"};
        fn = A.toLocaleString("en", o); 
        addRow(n,fn,r,tab);
        P=A;
       }
      
       
   

    }
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",calc(rate1,"1") +calc(rate2,"2")+calc(rate3,"3"));
    



</script>
        
    </div>
    

    <form action="hm4.html">
        <button class="back_button" >Return to Assignment-4 page</button>
    </form>
        
    
   <footer>
       This Webpage designed by Cagatay Ersoy 
   </footer>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you remember when your instructor discussed "meaningful variable names"? This is where that would really help others interpret your code and help you solve the problem.

Comment: ok, that was really helpful !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just add `Math.pow` and it works, the mistake was there.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="Cersoy-CNIT133-Assignments-4-part2" content="Cersoy-CNIT133-Assignments-4part2">
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>

<link href="../Assignment_all.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">



<title>Cersoy-CNIT133-Assignments_4-Part2</title>
<style>
    #main{
        background-color: rgb(222, 209, 135);
        margin:  auto;
        height: 30%;
        width: 50%;
        padding: 1em;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }
    table{
        margin:  auto;
        width: 50%;
    }
   
    th{
        border: solid 1px black;
        background-color: maroon;
        color: white;
    }
    td{
        border: solid 1px black;
        background-color: rgb(201, 255, 4);
        color: blue;
    }  
    
</style>

</head>
<body>
    
    <header>
        Cersoy-CNIT133-Assignments 4-Part2
    </header>
    <div id="main">
       <table id="table1" >
        <tr>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Amount of deposit</th>
            <th>Intrest Rate</th>
            
        </tr>
        </table>
        <table id="table2" >
        <tr>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Amount of deposit</th>
            <th>Intrest Rate</th>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <table id="table3" >
        <tr>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Amount of deposit</th>
            <th>Intrest Rate</th>
        </tr>
        </table>

<script>
        
        
        
    var rate1=5;rate2=6;rate3=7;
   
     function addRow(a,b,c,t) {
    var table=0;
    if(t==1){table = document.getElementById("table1");}
  
    if(t==2){
    table = document.getElementById("table2");
    }
    else if(t==3){
    table = document.getElementById("table3");
    }
    
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    cell1.innerHTML = a;
    cell2.innerHTML = b;
    cell3.innerHTML = c;
    
     }
    function calc(rate,tab){
       var P=1000,A=0,n=0;
        
       
       r=rate.toFixed(2)
       r=r/100;
      
       
       
       for(n=1;n<=10;n++){
        
        A=(P*(Math.pow((1+r),n)));
        
        var fn,o;

        o = {style: "currency", currency: "USD",minimumFractionDigits: 2,maximumFractionDigits: 2};
        fn = A.toLocaleString("en", o); 
        addRow(n,fn,r,tab);
        P=A;
       }
      
       
   

    }
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",calc(rate1,"1") +calc(rate2,"2")+calc(rate3,"3"));
    



</script>
        
    </div>
    

    <form action="hm4.html">
        <button class="back_button" >Return to Assignment-4 page</button>
    </form>
        
    
   <footer>
       This Webpage designed by Cagatay Ersoy 
   </footer>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the options object used for `.toLocalString()` to this:

```
 A.toLocaleString(undefined, {
  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
  maximumFractionDigits: 2
})
```

You have several errors in your HTML that you should also consider fixing.